# How do I pause playback on an embedded mp4 when clicking on a dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, carousel, mp4

I am using the code from the QuickQuiz https://github.com/UrbanInstitute/quick-quiz and have modified the code to use an embedded `video` (mp4) instead of an img, which loads from a json file- and also to use the SweetAlert2 library instead of the first SweetAlert, which was originally implemented. I want to pause the playback of each `video` when any one of the four 
`quiz-btn btn`
 buttons are clicked. The buttons all trigger the SweetAlert2 dialog using `swal.Fire`.

I have tried including script on the page like this:

```
document.querySelector("#quiz > div > div.item.active > div.quiz-answers > div:nth-child(1)").addEventListener("click",function() {
document.querySelector("#quiz > div > div.item.active > div.ncc.text-center > video").pause();});
```

and I have also tried

```
$('.quiz-button btn').on('click', function() {
        $('#video').attr('src', ''); });
```

directly in the code. The only thing I was successful with was getting the first video to stop playing when clicking the buttons- but none of the following videos would stop playing. Please help, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common issue, you will want to change your click function as follows:

**change** 
`$('.quiz-button btn').on('click', function() {`

**to**

`$(document).on('click','.quiz-button btn', function() {`